# Enum and string match

Tags: c#, enums

I'm essentially trying to read an xml file. One of the values has a suffix, e.g. "`30d`". This is meant to mean '30 days'. So I'm trying to convert this to a `DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)`. To read this field in the XML, i decided to use an Enum:

```
enum DurationType { Min = "m", Hours = "h", Days = "d" }
```

Now I'm not exactly sure how exactly to approach this efficiently (I'm a little daft when it comes to enums). Should I separate the suffix, in this case "d", out of the string first, then try and match it in the `enum` using a `switch` statement?

I guess if you dumb down my question, it'd be: What's the best way to get from `30d`, to `DateTime.Now.AddDays(30)` ?

Comment: Is it possible that the value will have a mixture, such as "1d 12h"?

Comment: can you have a suffix like 30d5h6m or 25d7m?

Comment: It'll only be XXy: where X = int, and y = suffix: d/m/h

Comment: Badly structured XML.... it would be better if the period could be specified separately to the amount, i.e. they are in different attributes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make an ExtensionMethod to parse the string and return the DateTime you want

Something like:

```
    public static DateTime AddDuration(this DateTime datetime, string str)
    {
        int value = 0;
        int mutiplier = str.EndsWith("d") ? 1440 : str.EndsWith("h") ?  60 : 1;
        if (int.TryParse(str.TrimEnd(new char[]{'m','h','d'}), out value))
        {
            return datetime.AddMinutes(value * mutiplier);
        }
        return datetime;
    }
```

Usage:

```
 var date = DateTime.Now.AddDuration("2d");
```

Comment: I like this.  No regex, no enum and just a couple lines of code.  Simple and to the point.  Good job.

Comment: Definitely the simplest answer here. Only thing I would change is split the string by a " " and run it through a foreach loop so it can accept values like DateTime.Now.AddDuration("12d 2h 30m");

Answer (score 5):

This seems like a good place to use regular expressions; specifically, capture groups.

Below is a working example:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RegexCaptureGroups
{
    class Program
    {
        // Below is a breakdown of this regular expression:
        // First, one or more digits followed by "d" or "D" to represent days.
        // Second, one or more digits followed by "h" or "H" to represent hours.
        // Third, one or more digits followed by "m" or "M" to represent minutes.
        // Each component can be separated by any number of spaces, or none.
        private static readonly Regex DurationRegex = new Regex(@"((?<Days>\d+)d)?\s*((?<Hours>\d+)h)?\s*((?<Minutes>\d+)m)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        public static TimeSpan ParseDuration(string input)
        {
            var match = DurationRegex.Match(input);

            var days = match.Groups["Days"].Value;
            var hours = match.Groups["Hours"].Value;
            var minutes = match.Groups["Minutes"].Value;

            int daysAsInt32, hoursAsInt32, minutesAsInt32;

            if (!int.TryParse(days, out daysAsInt32))
                daysAsInt32 = 0;

            if (!int.TryParse(hours, out hoursAsInt32))
                hoursAsInt32 = 0;

            if (!int.TryParse(minutes, out minutesAsInt32))
                minutesAsInt32 = 0;

            return new TimeSpan(daysAsInt32, hoursAsInt32, minutesAsInt32, 0);
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ParseDuration("30d"));
            Console.WriteLine(ParseDuration("12h"));
            Console.WriteLine(ParseDuration("20m"));
            Console.WriteLine(ParseDuration("1d 12h"));
            Console.WriteLine(ParseDuration("5d 30m"));
            Console.WriteLine(ParseDuration("1d 12h 20m"));

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Below is an alternative, slightly more condensed version of the above, though I'm not sure which one I prefer more.  I'm usually not a fan of overly dense code.
I adjusted the regular expression to put a limit of 10 digits on each number.  This allows me to safely use the `int.Parse` function, because I know that the input consists of at least one digit and at most ten (unless it didn't capture at all, in which case it would be empty string: hence, the purpose of the ParseInt32ZeroIfNullOrEmpty method).

```
        // Below is a breakdown of this regular expression:
        // First, one to ten digits followed by "d" or "D" to represent days.
        // Second, one to ten digits followed by "h" or "H" to represent hours.
        // Third, one to ten digits followed by "m" or "M" to represent minutes.
        // Each component can be separated by any number of spaces, or none.
        private static readonly Regex DurationRegex = new Regex(@"((?<Days>\d{1,10})d)?\s*((?<Hours>\d{1,10})h)?\s*((?<Minutes>\d{1,10})m)?", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        private static int ParseInt32ZeroIfNullOrEmpty(string input)
        {
            return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? 0 : int.Parse(input);
        }

        public static TimeSpan ParseDuration(string input)
        {
            var match = DurationRegex.Match(input);

            return new TimeSpan(
                ParseInt32ZeroIfNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["Days"].Value),
                ParseInt32ZeroIfNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["Hours"].Value),
                ParseInt32ZeroIfNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["Minutes"].Value),
                0);
        }
```

EDIT: Just to take this one more step, I've added another version below, which handles days, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds, with a variety of abbreviations for each.  I split the regular expression into multiple lines for readability.  Note, I also had to adjust the expression by using `(\b|(?=[^a-z]))` at the end of each component: this is because the "ms" unit was being captured as the "m" unit. The special syntax of "?=" used with "[^a-z]" indicates to match the character but not to "consume" it.

```
    // Below is a breakdown of this regular expression:
    // First, one to ten digits followed by "d", "dy", "dys", "day", or "days".
    // Second, one to ten digits followed by "h", "hr", "hrs", "hour", or "hours".
    // Third, one to ten digits followed by "m", "min", "minute", or "minutes".
    // Fourth, one to ten digits followed by "s", "sec", "second", or "seconds".
    // Fifth, one to ten digits followed by "ms", "msec", "millisec", "millisecond", or "milliseconds".
    // Each component may be separated by any number of spaces, or none.
    // The expression is case-insensitive.
    private static readonly Regex DurationRegex = new Regex(@"
        ((?<Days>\d{1,10})(d|dy|dys|day|days)(\b|(?=[^a-z])))?\s*
        ((?<Hours>\d{1,10})(h|hr|hrs|hour|hours)(\b|(?=[^a-z])))?\s*
        ((?<Minutes>\d{1,10})(m|min|minute|minutes)(\b|(?=[^a-z])))?\s*
        ((?<Seconds>\d{1,10})(s|sec|second|seconds)(\b|(?=[^a-z])))?\s*
        ((?<Milliseconds>\d{1,10})(ms|msec|millisec|millisecond|milliseconds)(\b|(?=[^a-z])))?",
        RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

    private static int ParseInt32ZeroIfNullOrEmpty(string input)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(input) ? 0 : int.Parse(input);
    }

    public static TimeSpan ParseDuration(string input)
    {
        var match = DurationRegex.Match(input);

        return new TimeSpan(
            ParseInt32ZeroIfNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["Days"].Value),
            ParseInt32ZeroIfNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["Hours"].Value),
            ParseInt32ZeroIfNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["Minutes"].Value),
            ParseInt32ZeroIfNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["Seconds"].Value),
            ParseInt32ZeroIfNullOrEmpty(match.Groups["Milliseconds"].Value));
    }
```

Comment: This is definitely the most expandable approach and probably a more universal acceptable way to do what the OP is asking.

Answer (score 3):

**update:**
Don't vote for this.  I'm leaving it simply because it's an alternative approach.  Instead look at sa_ddam213 and Dr. Wily's Apprentice's answers.

> Should I separate the suffix, in this case "d", out of the string
>   first, then try and match it in the enum using a switch statement?

Yes.

For a fully working example:

```
private void button1_Click( object sender, EventArgs e ) {
    String value = "30d";

    Duration d = (Duration)Enum.Parse(typeof(Duration), value.Substring(value.Length - 1, 1).ToUpper());
    DateTime result = d.From(new DateTime(), value);

    MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
}



enum Duration { D, W, M, Y };

static class DurationExtensions {
    public static DateTime From( this Duration duration, DateTime dateTime, Int32 period ) {
        switch (duration)
        {
          case Duration.D: return dateTime.AddDays(period);
          case Duration.W: return dateTime.AddDays((period*7));
          case Duration.M: return dateTime.AddMonths(period);
          case Duration.Y: return dateTime.AddYears(period);

          default: throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("duration");
        }
     }
    public static DateTime From( this Duration duration, DateTime dateTime, String fullValue ) {
        Int32 period = Convert.ToInt32(fullValue.ToUpper().Replace(duration.ToString(), String.Empty));
        return From(duration, dateTime, period);
    }
}
```

Comment: I had to quote the question in order to get past the minimum character "feature". ;)

Comment: Removed my answer, you finished it before me. I think a RegEx is probably the most obvious answer, but this is closer to what he was going for. As a rule though, you should use Enum.TryParse to avoid throwing an exception.

Comment: @Corylulu: I actually have half a mind to remove my own answer.  I really like sa_ddam213's answer better.  With just some minor error handling I'd throw that into production.

Comment: @ChrisLively Yeah, it's probably best. sa_ddam213's is good, but I think Dr. Wily's Apprentice's is best. If both answers were combined, it would be even better. But Dr's will work for using more than just 1 value e.g. "12d 2h 30m"

Answer (score 2):

I really don't see how using an `enum` helps here.

Here's how I might approach it.

```
string s = "30d";

int typeIndex = s.IndexOfAny(new char[] { 'd', 'w', 'm' });
if (typeIndex > 0)
{
    int value = int.Parse(s.Substring(0, typeIndex));
    switch (s[typeIndex])
    {
        case 'd':
            result = DateTime.Now.AddDays(value);
            break;
        case 'w':
            result = DateTime.Now.AddDays(value * 7);
            break;
        case 'm':
            result = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(value);
            break;
    }
}
```

Depending on the reliability of your input data, you might need to use `int.TryParse()` instead of `int.Parse()`. Otherwise, this should be all you need.

Note: I've also written a `sscanf()` replacement for .NET that would handle this quite easily. You can see the code for that in the article [A sscanf() Replacement for .NET](http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/strings/a-sscanf-replacement-for-net).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code, assuming that values like "30d" are in a string 'val'.

```
DateTime ConvertValue(string val) {
    if (val.Length > 0) {
        int prefix = Convert.ToInt32(val.Length.Remove(val.Length-1));
        switch (val[val.Length-1]) {
        case 'd': return DateTime.Now.AddDays(prefix);
        case 'm': return DateTime.Now.AddMonths(prefix);
        // etc.
    }
    throw new ArgumentException("string in unexpected format.");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of a console application example/tutorial:

```
enum DurationType
{
    [DisplayName("m")]
    Min = 1,
    [DisplayName("h")]
    Hours = 1 * 60,
    [DisplayName("d")]
    Days = 1 * 60 * 24
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string input1 = "10h";
        string input2 = "1d10h3m";

        var x = GetOffsetFromDate(DateTime.Now, input1);
        var y = GetOffsetFromDate(DateTime.Now, input2);

    }

    private static Dictionary<string, DurationType> suffixDictionary
    {
        get
        {
            return Enum
                .GetValues(typeof (DurationType))
                .Cast<DurationType>()
                .ToDictionary(duration => duration.GetDisplayName(), duration => duration);
        }
    }

    public static DateTime GetOffsetFromDate(DateTime date, string input)
    {
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"(\d+)([a-zA-Z]+)");
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            int numberPart = Int32.Parse(match.Groups[1].Value);
            string suffix = match.Groups[2].Value;
            date = date.AddMinutes((int)suffixDictionary[suffix]);
        }
        return date;
    }


}


[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class DisplayNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public DisplayNameAttribute(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    protected String name;
    public String Name { get { return this.name; } }
}

public static class ExtensionClass
{
    public static string GetDisplayName<TValue>(this TValue value) where TValue : struct, IConvertible
    {
        FieldInfo fi = typeof(TValue).GetField(value.ToString());
        DisplayNameAttribute attribute = (DisplayNameAttribute)fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayNameAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault();
        if (attribute != null)
            return attribute.Name;
        return value.ToString();
    }
}
```

Uses an attribute to define your suffix, uses the enum value to define your offset.

Requires:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

It may be considered a hack to use the enum integer value but this example will still let you parse out all the Enums (for any other use like switch case) with little tweaks.

Answer (score 0):

Enums can't be backed with non-numeric types, so string-based enums are out.  It's possible you may be overthinking it.  Without knowing any more about the problem, the most straightforward solution seems to be splitting off the last character, converting the rest to an int, and then handling each final char as a separate case.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using regexp to strip the number first and than execute [Enum.Parse Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/essfb559.aspx) to evaluate the value of the enum. Than you can use a switch (see Corylulu's answer) to get the right offset, based on the parsed number and enum value.